# VSCode not displaying any syntax errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

[image: Screenshot]

Earlier it used to show errors but suddenly all gone... no errors.
I also tried previously given solutions but didn't work.
I'm new to programming so kindly explain in steps.
Thank you :)

Comment: The intellisense underlining is done with c_cpp_properties.json Are you sure the file contains something valid? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I mistakenly disabled the ERROR SQUIGGLES, while writing C++ code.

enable_squiggles

You can enable them by navigating to FILE > PREFERENCES > SETTINGS.

Type squiggles. Choose 'EnableIfIncludesResolve' or 'Enabled'.

And make sure to do it in workspace settings ( I was doing it in user settings and was still not getting errors :D )

Answer (score 0):

Do <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, and type `settings.json`.

You will find the file which contains the value:

```
"C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": "Disabled"
```

Change it to: `Enabled`.